# VB.Net: Space between dynamically added controls on form increases if you pause

Tags: vb.net, scroll

**Purpose:**
Create textboxes and labels dynamically and place them on the form. I've enabled the AutoScroll setting on the form so as to be able to see all the controls.

**Problem:**
Clicking the 'add' button without more than a seconds pause creates no problem. However, at some (random) point the space between the controls become arbitrarily large. It seems to have something to do with the amount of time I wait to click the button for some reason.

**More Details:**

- There is no timer on the form, so I don't see how the factor 'time' could have *any* effect on the spacing
- The only variable affecting the position of the controls is the number of controls added (which I've checked during run-time - it checks out). The rest are constants.
- I've tried to do exactly the same on a panel. The same problem occurrs.
- It is never the same unwanted distance that is added, but it seems to be increasing the longer you wait.

My form:

```
Public Class Form1


    'Public
    Public MyTextBox, boxes(0), minboxes(0), maxboxes(0), cusboxes(0) As TextBox
    Public lngTextboxCount, lngCusboxCount As Long
    Public MyLabel As Label

    'Local


    'Settings
    Public lngAntalTests As Long = 10000

    Public Const lngTextboxHeight As Long = 20
    Public Const lngTextboxLength As Long = 100
    Public Const lngTextboxCusLength = 300
    Public Const lngTextboxLeft As Long = 20
    Public Const lngTextboxSpace As Long = 40
    Public Const lngTextboxVerticalSpace As Long = 30
    Public Const lngLabelIndent As Long = 3

    'Enums
    Public Enum BoxType
        IntMin
        IntMax
        Label
        Custom
    End Enum

    Public Enum VariableType
        Numeric
        Custom
    End Enum

    'BUTTONS
    Private Sub btnAddSingleNumeric_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddSingleNumeric.Click
        Call mdlAddControl.AddSingleControl(VariableType.Numeric)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAddSingleCustom_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddSingleCustom.Click
        Call mdlAddControl.AddSingleControl(VariableType.Custom)
    End Sub

    'Load Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Call InitialScript()

        txtAntal.Text = CStr(lngAntalTests)

    End Sub

    Private Sub InitialScript()
        lngTextboxCount = 0
        lngCusboxCount = 0
    End Sub


End Class
```

My module:

```
Module mdlAddControl
    Public Sub AddSingleControl(ByVal vartype As Form1.VariableType)
        Form1.lngTextboxCount += 1
        Select Case vartype
            Case Form1.VariableType.Numeric
                Call AddTextbox(Form1.BoxType.Label, Form1.VariableType.Numeric)
                Call AddTextbox(Form1.BoxType.IntMin, Form1.VariableType.Numeric)
                Call AddTextbox(Form1.BoxType.IntMax, Form1.VariableType.Numeric)
            Case Form1.VariableType.Custom
                Call AddTextbox(Form1.BoxType.Custom, Form1.VariableType.Custom)
        End Select
    End Sub

    'TOOLS


    Public Sub AddTextbox(ByVal boxtype As Form1.BoxType, ByVal vartype As Form1.VariableType)
        Form1.MyTextBox = New TextBox
        With Form1.MyTextBox
            .Height = Form1.lngTextboxHeight
            .Width = Form1.lngTextboxLength
            .Left = Form1.lngTextboxLeft
            .Top = (Form1.lngTextboxHeight + Form1.lngTextboxSpace) * Form1.lngTextboxCount
            Select Case vartype
                Case vartype.Custom
                    Form1.lngCusboxCount += 1
                    .Width = Form1.lngTextboxCusLength
                    ReDim Preserve Form1.cusboxes(Form1.lngCusboxCount - 1)
                    Form1.cusboxes(Form1.lngCusboxCount - 1) = Form1.MyTextBox
                Case vartype.Numeric
                    .Width = Form1.lngTextboxLength
                    Select Case boxtype
                        Case Form1.BoxType.Label
                            .Left = Form1.lngTextboxLeft
                            ReDim Preserve Form1.boxes(Form1.lngTextboxCount - 1)
                            Form1.boxes(Form1.lngTextboxCount - 1) = Form1.MyTextBox
                        Case Form1.BoxType.IntMin
                            .Left = .Width + Form1.lngTextboxVerticalSpace + Form1.lngTextboxLeft
                            ReDim Preserve Form1.minboxes(Form1.lngTextboxCount - 1)
                            Form1.minboxes(Form1.lngTextboxCount - 1) = Form1.MyTextBox
                        Case Form1.BoxType.IntMax
                            .Left = .Width * 2 + Form1.lngTextboxVerticalSpace * 2 + Form1.lngTextboxLeft
                            ReDim Preserve Form1.maxboxes(Form1.lngTextboxCount - 1)
                            Form1.maxboxes(Form1.lngTextboxCount - 1) = Form1.MyTextBox
                    End Select
            End Select
            Call PlaceLabel(Form1.lngTextboxCount, boxtype, vartype)
        End With
        Form1.Controls.Add(Form1.MyTextBox)
    End Sub

    Public Sub PlaceLabel(ByVal lngTextboxNumber As Long, ByVal boxtype As Form1.BoxType, ByVal vartype As Form1.VariableType)
        Form1.MyLabel = New Label
        With Form1.MyLabel
            .Top = (Form1.lngTextboxHeight + Form1.lngTextboxSpace) * lngTextboxNumber - 24
            Select Case boxtype
                Case Form1.BoxType.Label
                    .Text = "Variable Label" & lngTextboxNumber - Form1.lngCusboxCount
                    .Left = Form1.lngTextboxLeft - Form1.lngLabelIndent
                Case Form1.BoxType.IntMin
                    .Text = "Minimum Interval"
                    .Left = Form1.lngTextboxLength + Form1.lngTextboxVerticalSpace + Form1.lngTextboxLeft - Form1.lngLabelIndent
                Case Form1.BoxType.IntMax
                    .Text = "Maximum Interval"
                    .Left = Form1.lngTextboxLength * 2 + Form1.lngTextboxVerticalSpace * 2 + Form1.lngTextboxLeft - Form1.lngLabelIndent
                Case Form1.BoxType.Custom
                    .Text = "Custom Code " & Form1.lngCusboxCount
                    .Left = Form1.lngTextboxLeft - Form1.lngLabelIndent
            End Select
        End With
        Form1.Controls.Add(Form1.MyLabel)
    End Sub

End Module
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Doesn't have anything to do with "pausing", everything to do with you scrolling the window.  You must add the form's AutoScrollPosition to the control's Left and Top properties.

Comment: That sounds very likely. Just tested it out - there's no problem if I don't scroll at any point.
Can you elaborate on how I add the form's AutoScrollPosition like you said? Thanks!